# Subject-verb number agreement relating to "services"

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

I understand the subject-verb number agreement rule but had a hard time locating answers relating to types of and use of the word "services." I assume that you don't use plural types if using "services" since services is plural and refers to the combination of both, but I'm doubtful because I can't find the answer - I think the first examples are correct, but would like to be able to answer why its correct, example:

Publication and graphic art products and services...

or

Publications and graphic arts products and services...

Another example:

The department should account for publication and graphic art service expenditures

or

The department should account for publication and graphic art services expenditures

Comment: Your phrase: Publication and graphic art products and services. is wonky. What is being published exactly?

Comment: @Lambie - refers to numerous editorial, graphic, and writing products and services for documents and posters available to various departments.

Comment: What is modifying what? It's ambiguous. Compare "He brought pork and beef sandwiches and cakes" - is there pork and beef in the cakes?

Comment: "publication and graphic art service expenditures" is also a very awkward phrase and ambiguous phrase, and you should consider rephrasing to something like "expenditure on publication and on graphic art services". I guess you're Chinese in which case piling up noun after noun is more common, but you are better using prepositions and other words to express the logical relationship between the nouns.

Comment: editorial, graphic and writing products does not make sense.